# React, can't set state based on current state(state one step behind)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm absolutely lost with React async setState :(

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fcc-react-calc-current-q25n1)

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: when I click operator button (App.js line 81-98) , I take current(new\updated) `state.input`, 'format' it with my `fixInput` function (App.js line 7-22, it takes `state.input` and  `event.target.textContent`, returns new string), and set the result as new `state.input` value.

```
//App.js
function fixInput(inputStr, currentOp) {
  const lastTwoOp = /([+\-*/]{2})$/;
  const lastThreeOp = /([+\-*/]{3})$/; //
  const allowTwo = /(\*|\/)-/; //don't replace *- and /-
  //this  is not  working correctly
  if (lastTwoOp.test(inputStr) && !allowTwo.test(inputStr)) {
    // if there are 2 operators and those are not the allowed combinations, replace  them with the last operator
    inputStr = inputStr.slice(0, -2) + currentOp;
  } else if (lastThreeOp.test(inputStr)) {
    // if there are 3 operators, replace  them with the last operator
    inputStr = inputStr.slice(0, -3) + currentOp;
  } else {
    inputStr += currentOp;
  }
  return inputStr;
}

const init = () => ({
  input: "",
  output: 0,
  showInput: false,
  decimal: false,
  clickedOp: ""
});

export default class App extends Component {
  state = init();

  // HANDLERS
  handleCeClick = () => {
    this.setState(init);
  };

  handleNumClick = (e) => {
    const { input } = this.state;
    const value = e.target.textContent;
    if (e.target.id === "zero" && +input === 0) {
      //if there's 0 in input and 0 is clicked, do nothing
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      //add number to input,showinput, reset operators number
      this.setState((state) => ({
        input: input + value,
        showInput: true,
        opnum: 0
      }));
    }
  };

  handleDecClick = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.textContent;
    const { input, decimal } = this.state;
    if (decimal === true) {
      //if there's decimal in the input, do nothing
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      //add decimal to the input
      if (!input) {
        this.setState({
          input: "0."
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          input: input + value
        });
      }
      //default behavior: set decimal to true and show the input
      this.setState({
        decimal: true,
        showInput: true
      });
    }
  };

  handleOperClick = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.textContent;
    const fixedInput = fixInput(this.state.input, value);

    this.setState(
      (state, props) => {
        return {
          input: fixedInput,
          decimal: false,
          showInput: true,
          latestOper: value
        };
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.input); //current state here  i want to  use this value in fixInput function and  set as  new input state:/
      }
    );
  };

  handleEqualsClick = () => {
    const { input } = this.state;
    //todo ? if the last char is oper, delete it
    // console.log(input);
    let result = +eval(input).toFixed(7).toString();

    if (result.length > 11) {
      result = result.slice(0, 11);
    }
    this.setState((state) => ({
      showInput: false,
      output: result,
      input: result //test14
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const handlers = {
      handleCeClick: this.handleCeClick,
      handleNumClick: this.handleNumClick,
      handleOperClick: this.handleOperClick,
      handleEqualsClick: this.handleEqualsClick,
      handleDecClick: this.handleDecClick,
      handleInput: this.handleInput
    };
    const { input, output, showInput } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Display output={output} input={input} showInput={showInput} />
        <Keypad {...handlers} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
//Display.js
const Display = (props) => {
  //on equals  click  show  the  output ,  if  input continues  , show input, change showoutput
  let { input, output, showInput } = props;

  return (
    <div id="display" className="display_font">
      {showInput ? input : output}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
//Keypad.js
const Keypad = (props) => {
  return (
    <div id="keypad">
      <button id="clear" onClick={props.handleCeClick}>
        CE
      </button>
      <button id="seven" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        7
      </button>
      <button id="eight" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        8
      </button>
      <button id="nine" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        9
      </button>
      <button id="add" onClick={props.handleOperClick}>
        +
      </button>
      <button id="four" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        4
      </button>
      <button id="five" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        5
      </button>
      <button id="six" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        6
      </button>
      <button id="subtract" onClick={props.handleOperClick}>
        -
      </button>
      <button id="one" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        1
      </button>
      <button id="two" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        2
      </button>
      <button id="three" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        3
      </button>
      <button id="multiply" onClick={props.handleOperClick}>
        *
      </button>
      <button id="zero" onClick={props.handleNumClick}>
        0
      </button>
      <button id="decimal" onClick={props.handleDecClick}>
        .
      </button>
      <button id="equals" onClick={props.handleEqualsClick}>
        =
      </button>
      <button id="divide" onClick={props.handleOperClick}>
        /
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

React setState is async, and it's not updating immediately, so i can access only previous state.input, i can log to console current state from setState callback, and i need to set a new state, which I cannot do from callback. i can't access current state, that is why my `fixInput` function is not working correctly( press  number  and repetitive  operators, eg `4++`, it  was expected  to  allow  to  add only two combinations of operators `*-` and `/-`

I did try to move things around in every way I could think of.

What's wrong with my approach? Is this possible with the structure i've got?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the issue is here. You want to pass the current state into the fixInput method? But you call it on the handle oper click anyway, right?

Comment: but you are passing the current state.. not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: by the way, you dont need to use the callback in setState if you are not actually using the old state / props, just pass a new state object

Comment: are you trying to pass the last test case?

Comment: @szczocik  i need both current state and clicked button textContent to create new  state ```input``` value with correct  operators

Comment: @andymccullough thank you  i know  it now, that was  part  of  my desperate experiments long ago

Comment: @KetanRamteke   exactly, thought i came up with  a good  plan, not so sure now

Comment: I made small changes to ```handleEqualClick()```, and it cleared all test cases. do check out.

Comment: @KetanRamteke if I sanitize input on equals click displayed characters won't be correct (even if the whole thing passes the test), e.g. you still can 8++ Do you mean that my plan is impossible? (sanitize ```state.input``` on each operator click)

Comment: well, you can definitely improve upon the given code. "Do you mean that my plan is impossible?", don't know your plan, but writing code to fulfill the objective of making a calculator is definitely not impossible.

Comment: @KetanRamteke  the code is ugly, yep.. _sanitize `state.input` on each operator click_  so that displayed characters  were  correct at each point too <= the plan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226109/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-annestezia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some clarifications:  I wanted 1) to pass  test #13, 2) see correct characters on display

[Ketan Ramteke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5669120/ketan-ramteke) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343791/6201900) is working for the test but not for characters.
There was a mistake in `fixInput` function, I tested `this.state.input` when I needed the updated version which is `this.state.input + value`.

```
function fixInput(inputStr, currentOp) {
    const lastTwoOp = /([+\-*/]{2})$/;
    const lastThreeOp = /([+\-*/]{3})$/;
    const allowTwo = /(\*|\/)-/;

    const toTest = inputStr + currentOp; //<= 

    if (lastTwoOp.test(toTest) && !allowTwo.test(toTest)) {
        inputStr = inputStr.slice(0, -1) + currentOp;
    } else if (lastThreeOp.test(toTest)) {
        inputStr = inputStr.slice(0, -2) + currentOp;
    } else {
        inputStr += currentOp;
    }
    return inputStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Everything seems okay to me, just sanitize the input equation according to the given specification and all the test cases will be fulfilled.

Make these changes to `handleEqualClick()` function:

```
  handleEqualsClick = () => {
    const { input } = this.state;
    //todo ? if the last char is oper, delete it
    // console.log(input);
    let eq = [];
    for (let ch of [...input]) {
      if (!eq.length) {
        eq.push(ch);
      } else {
        if (ch === "-") {
          eq.push("-");
        } else if ("+-*/".includes(ch) && "+-*/".includes(eq[eq.length - 1])) {
          while ("+-*/".includes(ch) && "+-*/".includes(eq[eq.length - 1])) {
            eq.pop();
          }
          eq.push(ch);
        } else {
          eq.push(ch);
        }
      }
    }
    let sanitizedInput = eq.join("");
    console.log(sanitizedInput);
    let result = +eval(sanitizedInput).toFixed(7).toString();
    console.log("result:", result);

    if (result.length > 11) {
      result = result.slice(0, 11);
    }
    this.setState((state) => ({
      showInput: false,
      output: result,
      input: result //test14
    }));
  };
```

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bfi3n)